# Why my AngularJS module isn't defined

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: '/templates/index.html',
        })
        .state('signup', {
            url: "/signup",
            templateUrl: '',
        })
    }
]);

module.exports = app;
```

When i'm running in in browser, it show me an error:
ReferenceError: module is not defined

What i'm doing wrong ? How to properly define module ?

Comment: have you referenced angular ?

Comment: post a jsfiddle reproducing

Comment: Yes. And it stands upper than my app file.

Comment: Here is jsfiidle reproduction http://jsfiddle.net/bvsvzrr5/40/

Comment: Fairly clear in fiddle you haven't loaded all scripts required

Comment: Even if i will not include any script, string "module.export" won't work. Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvsvzrr5/43/

Answer (score 0):

Add the references to ui-router and bootstrap to make it work.

here is the working [`app`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/bvsvzrr5/41/)

Comment: Even if i will not include any script, string "module.export" won't work. Here is jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/bvsvzrr5/43

Answer (score 0):

The console error message a few lines below the `module is not defined` gives a hint where the problem is:

> Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

Check if you have included the file containing `ui.router` into your page (i.e. HTML template) so that Angular can load it.